# Karma error - Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

**DEBUG LOG:**

```
E:\Projects\abb\Projects\WebApp\abb.web>karma start
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading karma-* from E:\Projects\abb\Projects\WebApp\abb
.web\node_modules
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin E:\Projects\abb\Projects\WebApp\abb.web\n
ode_modules/karma-chrome-launcher.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin E:\Projects\abb\Projects\WebApp\abb.web\n
ode_modules/karma-jasmine.
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at C:\Users\Kunal\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-8
6563066
DEBUG [launcher]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --
user-data-dir=C:\Users\Kunal\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-86563066 --no-default-brow
ser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disab
le-translate http://localhost:9876/?id=86563066
DEBUG [watcher]: Resolved files:
        E:/Projects/abb/Projects/WebApp/abb.web/node_modules/karma-jasmi
ne/lib/jasmine.js
        E:/Projects/abb/Projects/WebApp/abb.web/node_modules/karma-jasmi
ne/lib/adapter.js
        E:/Projects/abb/Projects/WebApp/abb.web/app/js/vendor/angular.js

        E:/Projects/abb/Projects/WebApp/abb.web/app/js/vendor/angular-ro
ute.js
        E:/Projects/abb/Projects/WebApp/abb.web/test/lib/angular-mocks.j
s
        E:/Projects/abb/Projects/WebApp/abb.web/app/js/app.debug.js
        E:/Projects/abb/Projects/WebApp/abb.web/test/unit/homepage.spec.
js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: E:\Projects\abb\Projects\WebApp\abb.web\nod
e_modules\karma\static/client.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: E:\Projects\abb\Projects\WebApp\abb.web\nod
e_modules\karma\static/karma.js
DEBUG [web-server]: upgrade /socket.io/1/websocket/9uv4dB4yQPjZ7sZcWUuH
DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket 9uv4dB4yQPjZ7sZcWUuH
WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
DEBUG [launcher]: Process Chrome exited with code 0
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir C:\Users\Kunal\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-8656
3066
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
DEBUG [launcher]: Restarting Chrome
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at C:\Users\Kunal\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-8
6563066
DEBUG [launcher]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --
user-data-dir=C:\Users\Kunal\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-86563066 --no-default-brow
ser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disab
le-translate http://localhost:9876/?id=86563066
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: E:\Projects\abb\Projects\WebApp\abb.web\nod
e_modules\karma\static/client.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: E:\Projects\abb\Projects\WebApp\abb.web\nod
e_modules\karma\static/karma.js
DEBUG [web-server]: upgrade /socket.io/1/websocket/ei81-LVHlsfeDeCXWUuI
DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket ei81-LVHlsfeDeCXWUuI
WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
DEBUG [launcher]: Process Chrome exited with code 0
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir C:\Users\Kunal\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-8656
3066
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
DEBUG [launcher]: Restarting Chrome
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at C:\Users\Kunal\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-8
6563066
DEBUG [launcher]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --
user-data-dir=C:\Users\Kunal\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-86563066 --no-default-brow
ser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disab
le-translate http://localhost:9876/?id=86563066
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: E:\Projects\abb\Projects\WebApp\abb.web\nod
e_modules\karma\static/client.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: E:\Projects\abb\Projects\WebApp\abb.web\nod
e_modules\karma\static/karma.js
DEBUG [web-server]: upgrade /socket.io/1/websocket/rpgHU0_UF1MnvCwCWUuJ
DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket rpgHU0_UF1MnvCwCWUuJ
DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
DEBUG [launcher]: Process Chrome exited with code 0
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir C:\Users\Kunal\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-8656
3066
```

**package versions:**
    Node version: v0.10.28

```
"karma": "^0.12.16",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.4",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5",
```

**config file:**

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Sat May 24 2014 22:34:35 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'app/js/vendor/angular.js',
        'app/js/vendor/angular-route.js',
        'test/lib/angular-mocks.js',
        'app/js/app.debug.js',
        'test/unit/**/*.spec.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [

    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {

    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

**Chrome opens up with localhost://9876 and shows "karma - starting"**

Not able to make karma work. Please help.

I have tried setting autowatch: true and disabling firewall but none of these worked.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this problem? I'm getting the exact same message: `Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.`

Comment: No, i switched to PhantomJS. That worked with respect to my tests.

Comment: Yeah i'm having the same problem on our build server. I thought It was due to something in teamcity but mabey its just a karma/chrome issue.

Comment: @AlienBishop and dss, you're probably running into the same problem as I am with the latest update from Chrome. I've created an issue for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472457/jenkins-karma-chrome-not-working-after-last-auto-update-of-chrome

Comment: Same issue here, works locally though, only issues on build server(teamcity)

Comment: Reinstalling karma chrome launcher usually fixes this issue for me. I try global and local both (not sure which one fixes it though) Try this `npm i -D karma-chrome-launcher` Your dep version is very old it seems. Nvrming this is very old question, just saw timestamp.

Answer (score 9):

As Mikey mentioned, setting the `NO_PROXY` works for me, however it is not via `export`, but I have to do it inside the *`karma.conf.js`* file for `Karma` to pick this env variable up.

`process.env.NO_PROXY = 'localhost, 0.0.0.0/4201, 0.0.0.0/9876';`
`process.env.no_proxy = 'localhost, 0.0.0.0/4201, 0.0.0.0/9876';`

Hopefully it helps some hopeless ppl like me for a day....

Comment: unfortunately this does not work for me on azure devops. still get the error that chromeheadless could not be captured within 60000 ms

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

1. Install [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/)

   ```bash
   npm install puppeteer --save-dev
   ```
2. Add this code to `karma.conf.js` at the very top of your module exports function:

   ```js
   const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
   process.env.CHROME_BIN = puppeteer.executablePath();
   ```
3. Disable chrome sandbox:

   ```js
   browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessCI'],
   customLaunchers: {
       ChromeHeadlessCI: {
           base: 'ChromeHeadless',
           flags: ['--no-sandbox']
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: What does puppeteer do, pray tell?

Comment: --no-sandbox works for me on win server 2019 as ci.  adding Puppeteer probably wasn't needed for me, but good to have anyways.

Comment: @ruffin [according to npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer), puppeteer is "A high-level API to control headless Chrome over the DevTools Protocol"

Answer (score 3):

Apparently karma files got corrupted, that's what helped me:

1. delete `node_modules` folder completely.
2. run `npm install`

Answer (score 2):

I was executing the command on the visual studio code terminal. When I switched to iTerm suddenly it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when I'm using my Karma package with chrome version 93 on the windows server edition. Previously my build was running when on 92 chrome version but after upgrading the chrome to 93 the builds started failing.

Rollbacking my chrome resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to update my global installation of Karma to the latest version.  I suspect that I could have also just re-installed the existing version as I think the Karma install had gotten corrupted because it didn't matter what browser I used Karma still couldn't connect to it (or it couldn't connect to Karma).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a `NO_PROXY` exports
e.g.: `export NO_PROXY="localhost, 0.0.0.0/4201, 0.0.0.0/9876"`

Answer (score 0):

Another cause is running outdated versions of karma and related packages (I suspect karma-chrome-launcher in particular).

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late. But try increasing the `captureTimeout` configuration value by a considerable factor. This might give the test script some time to capture the browser once it has completed initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on Jenkins builds server. Problem was with node-chrome docker container we used, which always referenced the latest image. When **downgraded** node-chrome to lower version (e.g. node16) the `ng test` started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was running `npm rebuild`. See [related gitlab discussion](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/154#issuecomment-334526843)

so for it to work I run all these:

```
npm install && npm rebuild && npm test
```